# Is a basis always a subset of the topology?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $B$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$. Is $B\subseteq\tau$ always true?

Comment: What do you think? Go back to the definition of a basis.

Comment: Yes, a basis of a topology consists of open sets in the topology.

Comment: Write down your definition of *basis for a topology* and you will have an answer.

Comment: @yifan The definition says that B is a subset of X but does say that B is a subset of T.

Comment: It shouldn’t be hard to prove, though. We can’t help you without knowing the specific definition you are using.

Comment: @gbd That is not correct, a basis is not a subset of $X$, assuming by this you mean the topological space. Rather, a basis **element** is a subset of $X$. The topology $\tau$ contains precisely all the open sets, by definition.

Comment: @YiFan I thought that there can be more that one topology on X. If this is true how can a topology contain all the open sets. Doesnt that mean that all the topologies on X are the same if they all contain all the open sets

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is there a way to prove this using the definition in Wikipedia for a basis?

Comment: Without a topology, a it is nonsense to say a subset of $X$ is open. A set is open in a topological space, which is a pair $(X,\tau)$ where $X$ is a set, and $\tau$ is a topology on $X.$ A set $U\subseteq X$ is called open in $(X,\tau)$ if and only if $U\in \tau.$ So yes, $\tau$ is exactly all the open sets in $(X,\tau).$ There are no open sets in $X$ alone.

Comment: (We sometimes say a set $U$ is open in $X.$ But we always have an implied topology in mind. A good writer would never say this if we had two different topologies on $X$ currently being discussed.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is there a way to prove $\mathcal B \subseteq \tau$?

Comment: The answer to your question falls right out of the definition of *basis*. The members of $\tau$ are precisely the unions of subsets of $B$, so if $U\in B$ then $U = \bigcup \{U\} \in \tau$.

Comment: It is if you use standard US notion of a basis of topology. But not if you follow Bourbaki.

Comment: "The definition says that B is a subset of X but does say that B is a subset of T". You do not say what $X$ is (presumably the topological space). And $B$ is certainly not defined as a subset of $X$. I therefore voted to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

By **definition** $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \tau$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base (not basis, usually) for the space $(X,\tau)$.

FYI, a family of subsets $\mathcal{N}$ of $X$ that is like a base for $(X,\tau)$ in the sense that

$$\forall O \in \tau: \forall x \in O: \exists N \in \mathcal{N}: x \in N \subseteq O$$

(another way of stating that all sets in the topology are unions of members from $\mathcal{N}$) is called a **network** for $(X,\tau)$. This can be a useful notion in some subbranches of general topology. A base is just a network that consists of open sets only.

Comment: Basis (and similarly subbasis) is accepted terminology, see for example the wikipedia page.

Comment: @YiFan real topologists say base.

Comment: Not sure why "real topologists" would obsess over such minor issues in terminology. Both are used interchangeably in many textbooks and articles (e.g. Munkres). Of course you're justified in preferring "base", but it's not wrong to say "basis".

Comment: @YiFan more copy editing is needed in journals and books obviously. People need to be educated. Etc.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that using "basis" instead of "base" makes one uneducated?

Comment: @YiFan FYI, in spite of what wikipedia says, it seems that all the classic references in topology (Willard, Engelking, Arkhangelskii, etc) all use "base" and not "basis".

Comment: @PatrickR I'm not aware of the history of the terms, but perhaps this is a more modern shift in terminology? The currently (afaik) most widely used introductory text in Topology, as well as a reference even for mathematicians, is the text by Munkres, which uses both interchangeably. I have seen also lectures by mathematicians such as Richard Borcherds who have used them interchangeably. I don't see why anyone should insist on one over the other.

Comment: @YiFan Munkres is never used as a standard reference by normal topologists. It's a text book, not intended as a reference. IMO if you'd quote it in a paper, the paper is disqualified (or its author). Stick to standard terminology, not one popularised by a (bad) text book or Wikipedia.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't know about topologists (I don't personally know any), but I know mathematicians in other fields who use it as a reference when they need to refer to results in Topology. If you think "basis" is nonstandard, you need more evidence to convince me of that.

Comment: @YiFan I was at a university with 3 topology full professors and did my PhD in it and attended conferences (and wrote some papers). Trust me, it's nonstandard.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma as I said, I don't necessarily prefer either "base" or "basis" over the other. However, given that both terms are in common use, I don't see a reason to make a fuss about it, when they are readily understood. Mathematics is about communication of ideas, not gate keeping some holy standard of "correct notation".

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I respect your experience, but no I will not "trust you" that the term is nonstandard, when there is plenty of evidence to the contrary. It might well be the case that this is a more modern shift in terminology for instance (just speculation, obviously I don't know for sure)

Comment: @YiFan I'll stop the discussion here. I stand by my words. You to yours.

Comment: Sure. Agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to come from thinking that every set $X$ has associated with it some open sets, and a basis consists of some of these open sets that generate a topology. This is incorrect. The very definition of open set is inherently associated with a topology.

**By definition**, an open set $U\subseteq X$ **is** an element of the topology $\tau$. So the notion of an open set falls out of the topology, not the other way. For example, in $\mathbb R$ with the standard Euclidean topology, the set $[0,1]$ is not open. However, in the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$, all sets are open and in particular $[0,1]$ is as well.

The notion of an open set is not inherent to the set $X$. It is inherent to the topological space $(X,\tau)$ where we have already specified the topology $\tau$. Somewhat confusingly, people often don't write out the topology in notation, leaving it implicit, especially for cases like the standard topology on Euclidean space. Perhaps this is the source of your confusion.

---

To answer the original question, by definition, a basis is a collection of open sets that generates the topology. But open sets are, by definition, elements of the topology. Therefore a basis is a collection of elements of the topology that generates it, in particular, it is a subset of the topology.